# How I select some tag in a range

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code: How I can use jQuery to select in range from first to end (I already commented) and change all `p` and `a` tag in that range to another color (may be yellow...).
(I want a solution can use even we have more tag between that range).

```
<div class="test1">
        <a> 1 </a>
        <p title="hihi" style="color:red"> 2 </p> <!-- first -->
        <p> 3 </p>
        <p> 4 </p>
        <a> 5.0 </a>
        <div> 5.1 </div>
        <a> 6.0 </a>
       <div> 5.1 </div>            
        <p> 7 </p>
        <p> 8</p>
        <p> 9</p>
        <span></span>
        <p> 10</p>//end
        <div>11</div>
        <p>12</p>
        <span>13</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: so, in this example, you want everything from the tag that's styled `color: red` to the end?

Answer (score 1):

Use `:gt()` and `:lt()` selectors (greater than and less than):

```
$('div.test1').find('(a,p):lt(13):gt(0)').css('color','yellow');
```

The `p` with 10 is a child element of div and has index 12, therefore it has to be less than 13 to include it in the range.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like this:

```
;(function($) {
    /** $(ele).childrenRange(MIXED VAR);
     *  Select a range of children elements using either integers or string selectors.
     *
     *      With Int Params
     *  @param (Integer) arg1 The lowest child's index value
     *  @param (Integer) arg2 The highest child's index value (not required)
     *
     *      With String Params
     *  @param (String) arg1 jQuery string selector for first child sought
     *  @param (String) arg1 jQuery string selector for last child sought (Not Required)
     *  */
    function childrenRange() {
        var $ele = arguments[0],
            args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)
        if ($ele && !($ele instanceof jQuery) && (typeof $ele == 'string' || $ele instanceof HTMLCollection || $ele instanceof Array)) $ele = $($ele);
        if ($ele) {
            var first = $ele.children(':first'),
                last = $ele.children(':last');
            if (!args.length) return $ele.children();
            if (1 <= args.length) {
                if ('number' == typeof args[0]) first = $ele.children().eq(args[0]);
                else if ('string' == typeof args[0]) first = $ele.children(args[0]).first();
            }
            if (2 == args.length) {
                if ('number' == typeof args[0]) last = $ele.children().eq(args[1]);
                else if ('string' == typeof args[0]) last = $ele.children(args[1]).last();
            }
            return first.nextUntil(last).andSelf().add(last);
        }
        throw new Error("Invalid Parent Selector");
    }
    $.extend({ childrenRange: childrenRange });
    $.fn.extend({
        childrenRange: function() {
            var args = [this];
            if (arguments.length) for (x in arguments) args.push(arguments[x]);
            return $.childrenRange.apply($, args);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Then you can use as simple as:

```
//  with just one string param
$('.test1').childrenRange('[style="color:red"]').css({ 'color': 'yellow' });
//  with just two string param (first, last)
$('.test1').childrenRange('[style="color:red"]', '.some-class').css({ 'color': 'yellow' });

//  with just 1 integers 
$('.test1').childrenRange(3).css({ 'color': 'yellow' });
//  with just 2 integers (first, last)
$('.test1').childrenRange(3, 5).css({ 'color': 'yellow' });
```

See it working in more ways at [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/y9ou6wyw/).

[See Also](https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/jQuery.findInRange)